# How to use "BasedOn" attribute for ListView WPF controls?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In a UserControl XAML file, I want to define a ListView based on the predefined style. So I write the following lines:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="2" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style
            TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
```

Though, for the `BasedOn` attribute, I get the error: `The resource "{x:Type ListViewItem}" could not be resolved.`.
If I replace the `ListViewItem` word with `ListBoxItem` or `TreeViewItem` the compilation is successful, but at runtime it raises a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception, specifying that the `BasedOn` attribute needs a `ListBoxItem`.
If I remove that attribute, it works, but it has a weird look.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you sure you really need a ListView, instead of the simpler ListBox? And how does it look when you don't set BasedOn at all?

Comment: What "predefined style" are you referring to?

Comment: I need several columns. Well, I could use a grid, but then ListViews are meant for what? I use the MahApps.Metro toolkit, with a dark theme (white text on black background). If I don't set BasedOn, every row has a blue border, and when I select a row, its background becomes very light blue, while the text remains white, and so it is difficult to read. The TreeView control I use in the same window works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MahApps.Metro`, you should base your `Style` on the `MetroListViewItem` resource:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListViewItem}">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`BasedOn` is used for Style inheritance, so it should be pointing to another ListViewItem `Style` that you've previously defined, not a type.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MyListViewItemBaseStyle}">
```